# Error injecting constructor, org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, gwt, tomcat, guice

Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

```
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter guiceFilter
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
  at eu.paedrtx.idatservice.dao.database.HibernateUtil.<init>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
  while locating eu.paedrtx.idatservice.dao.database.HibernateUtil
  while locating eu.paedrtx.idatservice.dao.database.IDatabase
    for parameter 0 at eu.paedrtx.idatservice.dao.IdatDAO.<init>(IdatDAO.java:29)
  while locating eu.paedrtx.idatservice.dao.IdatDAO
    for parameter 2 at eu.paedrtx.idatservice.jsonp.IdatServlet.<init>(IdatServlet.java:50)
  while locating eu.paedrtx.idatservice.jsonp.IdatServlet

1 error
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:767)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:789)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:74)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at eu.paedrtx.idatservice.dao.database.HibernateUtil.<init>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at eu.paedrtx.idatservice.dao.database.HibernateUtil$$FastClassByGuice$$9aaad1aa.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:107)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/MethodFilter
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl.getProxyFactoryFactory(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactoryInternal(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    ... 75 more
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/IDATService] startup failed due to previous errors
22.03.2011 09:52:43 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate destroy
INFO: WSSERVLET15: JAX-WS servlet destroyed
22.03.2011 09:52:43 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/IDATService] registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/IDATService] appears to have started a thread named [com.google.inject.internal.Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/IDATService] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/IDATService] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/IDATService] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/IDATService] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
22.03.2011 09:52:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/IDATService] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$1@53601a4f]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@4a5f634c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add to class path javassist.jar